# Line integral of vector field with singularity

Tags: integration, vector-fields, line-integrals

Supose a vector field $\vec{F}(x,y)$ has a singularity at $(x_0,y_0)$. If I wanted to evaluate the integral $$\int_{\gamma}\vec{F}.d \vec{r}$$ along $\gamma$, knowing that $(x_0, y_0) \in \gamma$, how should I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: what kind of singularity?

Comment: The field is not defined at this point (for example, $\vec{F}(x,y) = \frac{-y \vec{i} + x \vec{j}}{x^2 + y^2}$ is not defined at (0,0)).

Comment: If the field is not defined, neither is the integral, at least in the sense of Riemann.